# Return row number or true or false or value if condition is met - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I know this will sound odd, but is that scenario possible?

1st - I do not want to use a macro. So it has to be a formula.

Assuming I have this tree columns:

```
    A              B              C
1   01-Jan-2016    05-Jan-2016    White
2   01-Feb-2016    08-Feb-2016    Yelllow
3   01-Mar-2016    09-Mar-2016    Red
```

Let's suppose I give this date: 03-Mar-2016. Do we have a way to return Red if that date is found on that range? Or at least return row number where that condition is met?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$3,MATCH(1,(E1>=$A$1:$A$3)*(E1<=$B$1:$B$3),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl _Shift_Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but try to put 10-Mar-2016 on E1.. It still shows Red.

Comment: @FilipePires sorry had the third criterion of the MATCH wrong. see edit.